# Rspec failed with update in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is the rspec error for update in customers controller:

```
 5) CustomersController GET customer page 'update' should be successful
     Failure/Error: put 'update', id => 1, :customer => {:name => 'name changed'}
       <Customer(id: integer, name: string, short_name: string, contact: string, address: string, country: string, phone: string, fax: string, email: string, cell:
string, sales_id: integer, test_eng_id: integer, safety_eng_id: integer, web: string, category1_id: integer, category2_id: integer, active: boolean, biz_status: str
ing, input_by_id: integer, quality_system: string, employee_num: string, revenue: string, note: text, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
(class)> received :find with unexpected arguments
         expected: (1)
              got: ("1")
     # ./app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:44:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the rspec code:

```
it "'update' should be successful" do

  customer = mock_model(Customer) 
  Customer.should_receive(:find).with(1).and_return(customer)
  customer.stub(:update_attributes).and_return(true)    
  put 'update', :id => 1, :customer => {:name => 'name changed'}
  response.status.should == 302 #redirect()
end
```

Here is the update in controller:

```
  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer], :as => :roles_new_update)
      if @customer.changed
        @message = 'The following info have been changed\n' + @customer.changes.to_s
        @subject ='Customer info was changed BY' + session[:user_name]
        notify_all_in_sales_eng(@message,@subject)
      end  

      redirect_to session[('page'+session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym], :notice => 'Customer was updated successfaully!'
    else
      render 'edit', :notice => 'Customer was not updated!'
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The values posted (and accessed via the `params` hash) are strings. The easiest way to correct your test is to have `Customer.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(customer)`.

Notice we now have "1" (i.e. a String) as the expected argument instead of 1 (a FixNum).

Comment: Here is the error after using with("1"):  5) CustomersController GET customer page 'update' should be successful
     Failure/Error: put 'update', :id => 1, :customer => {:name => 'name changed'}
       Mock "Customer_1001" received unexpected message :changed with (no args)
     # ./app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:46:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: That's because you're calling `@customer.changed` in your code, but haven't stubbed that method. You need to either stub that method, or use a real model instance so that `@customer.changed` will evaluate properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. stub it like :    customer.stub(:changed).and_return(false) to bypass sending email. However stuck with another problem, which is how to test :  redirect_to session[('page'+session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym], :notice => 'Customer was updated successfaully!'?

Comment: Another question. By using stub to return value as desired, do we really test anything in code? Or just make it passed for self comfort.

Comment: You should be able to test that with `response.should redirect_to(session[('page'+session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym])`. The way your tests rspec tests work is that you test only one single thing in each test. Everything else is stubbed so that each test is independent. So you should use another test to check that `@customer.changed` works properly. That way you'll have proper test coverage.

Answer (score 1):

All params are passed through as strings and I believe the find method is doing an implicit conversation to an integer. Either make it explicit using to_i in the controller or change your spec to expect the string "1".